# Authentication in nodejs with express-session

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, express-session

I can't work the authentication in local, the database works correctly, indeed it saves the email and password properly, but when redirect to /secrets route it doesn't authorized, can anyone help me?

The authorization is based on local. I need that it give me the / secrets when I'm authenticated, but in that function it returns false, in the tutorial he writes the same code but something different for example he uses the then function instead of me using the await/async

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import session from 'express-session';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import os from 'dotenv'
import passport from 'passport';
import passport_local_mongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';

os.config()
const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const URL_mongo = process.env.dbUrl //url


const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    password:String
})


app.use(express.static("public"))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(session({secret:"parola",resave:false,saveUninitialized:false})) //cookie:{secure:true} 
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

mongoose.connect(URL_mongo,{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,})

userSchema.plugin(passport_local_mongoose)
const User= new mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
passport.use(User.createStrategy())
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render("home.ejs")
})
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs")
})

app.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    
})
app.get('/register', async(req, res) => {
    res.render("register.ejs")
})
app.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        User.register({ usernam: req.body.username }, req.body.password)
        passport.authenticate("basic",{successRedirect:"/secrets",failureMessage:"/"})(req,res,()=>{
            console.log("entrato") //check to see if it goes here and it does
            res.redirect("/secrets")
            
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

app.get('/secrets', async(req, res) => {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) { //here the error that redirects to login
        res.render("secrets.ejs")
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})

app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {
    res.render("submit.ejs")
})

app.listen(port,()=> {
    console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
})
```